# 18.04 xserver exits after login

Tags: 18.04, xorg, ubuntu-mate, gdm

I have a problem with X.
Right after login, I briefly see the icons on the desktop and my wallpaper. Immediately after that I find myself on the login screen again.

If I log in on another tty and try to start the Xserver with startx, it stops immediately without giving me any errors.

As window manager I use GDM3 and desktop environment is Mate.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you examined the contents of the `~/.xsession-errors` file?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check. Disk space (check if you have space left):

```
$ df
```

and permissions of /tmp (check if the first field is `drwxrwxrwt`):

```
 $ ls -ld /tmp
```

If the permissions on `/tmp` are not right, you can do:

```
$ sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: permissions of /tmp are correct and my disk still has 500GB free.